# loopback rest connection headers authorization

Tags: loopbackjs

I'm trying to access the Shopify Orders API in a Loopback application. I have the following data source:

```
"ShopifyRestDataSource": {
  "name": "ShopifyRestDataSource",
  "connector": "rest",
  "operations": [{
    "template": {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "https://mystore.myshopify.com/admin",
      "headers": {
        "accepts": "application/json",
        "content-type": "application/json"
      }
    },
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Basic MzdiOD..."
    },
    "functions": {
      "find": []
    }
  }]
}
```

And then I attempt a simple call:

```
var ds = app.dataSources.ShopifyRestDataSource;

ds.find(function(err, response, context) {
  if (err) throw err;
  if (response.error) {
    next('> response error: ' + response.error.stack);
  }
  console.log(response);
  next();
});
```

I'm getting the following exception message:

> Error: {"errors":"[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)"}
>       at callback (/order-api/node_modules/loopback-connector-rest/lib/rest-builder.js:529:21)

The Shopify API authenticates by basic HTTP authentication and I'm sure my request works since the same data works with curl. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you already tried turning on loopback's underlying DEBUG logging to see what is happening under the hood? `DEBUG=loopback:datasource:* node server/server.js` http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Setting-debug-strings.html

Comment: I just modified the original post with the error message that I'm getting back from the server - basically missing authentication. It's the same thing with or without DEBUG.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the "Loopback way" to do this and I couldn't wait, so I just wrote a simple https Node call. I'll paste this in here but I won't accept it as the answer. I'm still hoping someone will provide the right answer.

```
let response;

const options = {
  hostname: 'mystore.myshopify.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/admin/orders.json',
  method: 'GET',
  auth: `${instance.api_key}:${instance.password}`
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');

  let body = '';

  res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    body += chunk;
  });

  res.on('end', function() {
    let jsonResponse = JSON.parse(body);

    // application logic goes here

    response = 'ok';
  });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  response = e.message;
});

req.end();
```